cmake tar extract tar.gz without including the root directory
- files.tar.gz
    - file1
    - file2
    - files_3
        - file3

After extraction it should be:
- file1
- file2
- files3
    - file3

The same question has been asked like here: https://superuser.com/questions/899684/how-to-untar-an-archive-without-the-root-folder-but-keeping-the-full-hierarchy
However the issue is I want to do this from within cmake.
${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E tar

see: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html
CMAKE_COMMAND is too primitive. For example it doesn't even support the -C flag.  There is the custom_command but I rather not complicate the cmake file even more. Especially when this is such a basic functionality.

CMAKE also has a file(ARCHIVE_EXTRACT) but that again has no options other than the basic extract.
